# Obtener el id más reciente por fecha en mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

Tengo la siguiente tabla y estoy intentando sacar los ID, con su precio y fecha de cada producto según el idProducto elegido.

```
CREATE TABLE `precios_productos` (
  `idPrecioProducto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idProducto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idSupermercado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio` float NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `precios_productos` (`idPrecioProducto`, `idProducto`, `idSupermercado`, `precio`, `fecha`) VALUES
(28, 23, 18, 1.5, '2022-04-05'),
(48, 23, 18, 1.21, '2022-05-06'),
(49, 23, 18, 1.15, '2022-05-07'),
(56, 23, 18, 1.08, '2022-05-14'),
(86, 23, 18, 1.01, '2022-05-19');
```

Aquí la PK es idPrecioProducto y luego habría FK a idProducto e idSupermercado (que no detallo al realmente no venir al caso)

Lo que necesito es sacar, como comentaba, el precio más reciente de un producto en un supermercado o la lista de precios del producto en el supermercado.

Si hago esta consulta:

```
SELECT MAX(pp.fecha) as fecha, pp.idProducto, pp.idSupermercado, pr.precio, pp.idPrecioProducto, pr.idPrecioProducto
FROM precios_productos pp
LEFT JOIN precios_productos pr ON pp.idPrecioProducto=pr.idPrecioProducto
GROUP BY idProducto, idSupermercado
```

Me devuelve parcialmente lo que quiero (pero realmente lo único que está bien es la fecha, lo demás no concuerda con el resto de la tupla)

```
fecha   idProducto  idSupermercado  precio  idPrecioProducto    idPrecioProducto    
2022-05-19  23  18  1.5     28  28
2022-04-27  23  21  1.79    33  33
2022-05-14  23  23  0.56    84  84
```

Para este producto (idProducto = 23) sus precios serían:

```
idPrecioProducto    idProducto  idSupermercado  precio  fecha   
    28  23  18  1.5     2022-04-05
    48  23  18  1.21    2022-05-06
    49  23  18  1.15    2022-05-07
    56  23  18  1.08    2022-05-14
    86  23  18  1.01    2022-05-19
```

Si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia, se lo agradezco. Se que en realidad es una tontería, pero estoy algo enfrascado en esto.
Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

no es tan complicada la consulta, creo q está mal planteada.
Cree una tabla con tu codigo y probé esta consulta y me ha funcionado

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM precios_productos pp
WHERE pp.idProducto =23
ORDER BY fecha desc

Esto es en SQL server.

En el caso de no haber entendido yo la pregunta, recomiendo usar subconsultas en el from y en el where evitando hacer un join de la misma tabla.

Quedo pendiente.

Comment: No hay TOP en MySQL.

Comment: LIMIT entonces.

Answer (score 0):

Si efectivamente, quizás no me expliqué del todo bien.
Tras otro rato dándole mas vueltas, "creo" que lo he conseguido. No sé si será lo más eficiente posible la query, pero funciona. También haciendo algunas pruebas, para algunos supermercados, si me da los valores correctos y para otros no.

```
SELECT pp.idPrecioProducto, pp.producto, pp.precio, pp.fecha
FROM precios_productos pp
INNER JOIN precios_productos pr ON pr.idPrecioProducto=pp.idPrecioProducto AND pr.fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) as fecha FROM precios_productos p3 WHERE p3.idProducto=pp.idProducto)
WHERE pp.idSupermercado = 18
GROUP BY pp.idProducto, pp.idSupermercado
ORDER BY p.producto ASC
```

Al final lo que necesito es listar todos los productos que hay en un supermecado concreto, pero con su precio mas actual

Comment: Si, lo que planteas en este comentario es otra cosa pero ...
cual es el objetivo de hacer el join de pr con pp?

Comment: Mi objetivo simplemente es sacar todos los productos de un supermercado de esa tabla, con sus precios más recientes. Ya digo, es la única forma que de momento medio creo que funciona, pero le estoy viendo lagunas y creo que no está del todo bien